# How do you mock the asp.net mvc pipeline

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

How would you mock the ASP.NET MVC pipeline for testing?

Example i want to unit test a method in a controller.

That method has an attribute.

The attribute is part of the pipeline.

How do i mock the mock the httpcontext or the mvvc pipeline to test the method?

Comment: You don't. You design the controller and attributes in a way that can be testable without involving the MVC or any other framework

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what mocking framework you're using or what you mean by the pipeline. Here's an example of how you can mock the HttpContext (and all dependent objects) using FakeItEasy.

```
public static HttpContextBase FakeHttpContext()
{
    var context = A.Fake<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = A.Fake<HttpRequestBase>();
    var response = A.Fake<HttpResponseBase>();
    var session = A.Fake<HttpSessionStateBase>();
    var server = A.Fake<HttpServerUtilityBase>();

    A.CallTo( () => request.QueryString ).Returns( new NameValueCollection() );
    A.CallTo( () => request.Form ).Returns( new NameValueCollection() );
    A.CallTo( () => request.Headers ).Returns( new NameValueCollection() );

    A.CallTo( () => context.Request ).Returns( request );
    A.CallTo( () => context.Response ).Returns( response );
    A.CallTo( () => context.Session ).Returns( session );
    A.CallTo( () => context.Server ).Returns( server );

    return context;
}

public static void SetFakeControllerContext( Controller controller)
{
    var httpContext = FakeHttpContext();
    ControllerContext context = new ControllerContext( new RequestContext( httpContext, new RouteData() ), controller );
    controller.ControllerContext = context;
}
```

Then in your unit test you call `SetFakeControllerContext` passing an instance of the controller itself.

```
var controller = new HomeController();
Faker.SetFakeControllerContext(controller);
```

If you're trying to test that the attribute executes, you don't. You test the attribute and the controller separately. You don't need to test that the attribute runs because that's part of the infrastructure and it's not your job to test that.